# Why cannot music files be deleted, moved or renamed if any software is playing them?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, performance, filesystems

While rearranging my music collection, I keep running into the highly frustrating situation where Windows (10) refuses to let met delete, move or rename a file just because I'm having it playing at the same time, in either Media Player Classic or foobar2000. It seems to not matter which software is used; it's "blocking" any file operations.

But why is this? My rather old computer has more than enough RAM to hold an entire full day worth of lossless WAV audio entirely in its working memory without ever noticing it. So why aren't my 5-minute FLAC songs loaded into RAM by any of my media players?

Is there something I'm missing? Why don't media players just completely "copy" the data from the disk while/before playing it, so that I can freely move around, rename, delete, etc. any music file without having to care about closing down programs all the time? Is this just a leftover from the old days when an extra 4 MB of RAM was a major investment?

Comment: Because developers decided not to? It’s a waste of RAM after all. // Furthermore, reading the entire file into RAM isn’t enough. The software also has to _close_ the file.

Comment: @DanielB What is the problem with closing the file? And why is it a "waste"?

Comment: @Skor Because software doesn't need to keep the entire file in RAM. Notably iPods based on microdrives did this, but for a good reason: the drives would spin down very quickly to save power. On desktops this doesn't apply and the issue you've described is not something many users will run into.

Comment: This is true for any file in use.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, when a program opens a file, it also specifies the
permissions that it allows to other programs on the file.
If it opens the file in exclusive mode, then no other program can
do anything with the file.

The way the file-table is created, with file-entries just pointing to
disk data, a file can in principle be deleted or renamed while open,
since the file-data pointer stays valid as long as the file is open.

Conclusion : The problem is with the player that you are using,
not with Windows. If the player does not have an option for opening
the files in non-exclusive mode, then you need to find another
more permissive player.

Comment: "find another more permissive player." Yeah, good luck to me with that... There isn't any usable software period besides what I already mentioned.

Comment: In desperate times, you could use a program such as the old [unlocker](http://www.iobit.com/en/iobit-unlocker.php) which might still work or [its alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/iobit-unlocker/). Also, have you tried VLC?

Comment: Yes, it's the same in VLC, which I do have installed for special cases, but don't normally use because it's just so awful (apparently by design).

Comment: Also, I'm not a fan of those random utilities in this era of computers. They were really cool in the 1990s, but now I can't imagine that they *don't* contain malware/spying etc.

Comment: The well-known utilities can be trusted.